# How to add a macro button to toolbar or ribbon in Word?

Tags: macros, microsoft-word-2013

How can I add a button to a toolbar or the ribbon in Word 2013 to run a custom macro? I can run it using the keyboard but I want a button.

Answer (score 2):

In Word 2007 (or Excel or PowerPoint), you can “Choose commands from” “Macros” when you customize the Quick Access Toolbar (the button bar above or below the ribbon).

[image]